# How to split dates between two dates in excel using macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where i need to split dates between two dates (start date and end date).

For example: I have start date as 1-Dec-2014 and end date as 31-Dec-2014. 
How can i have macro code which should populate dates (only sundays) like:

```
7-Dec-2014   14-Dec-2014  21-DEc-2014  28-Dec-2014
```

in rows.

Comment: Have you written anything, any macro code for this ?

Comment: Could be achieved with formula without any macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `WeekDay` function, possible value for this function is

vbSunday (1)
vbMonday (2)
vbTuesday (3)
vbWednesday (4)
vbThursday (5)
vbFriday (6)
vbSaturday (7)

```
Sub LoopDates()
Dim d As Date
'Loop the days between two dates.
For d = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) To DateSerial(2015, 3, 1)
  If Weekday(d) = vbSunday Then
   Debug.Print d
  End If
Next
End Sub
```